# Image uploading using Multer Storage Cloudinary package

Tags: multer, cloudinary

I'm using "Multer Storage Cloudinary" npm package to upload images. I can successfully upload images, however, i need to paths to be dynamic.

From the docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary):

```
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  params: {
    folder: 'some-folder-name', // *** NEED TO CONTROL THIS!!! ***
    format: async (req, file) => 'png', // supports promises as well
    public_id: (req, file) => 'computed-filename-using-request',
  },
});
 
const parser = multer({ storage: storage });
 
app.post('/upload', parser.single('image'), function (req, res) {
  res.json(req.file);
});
```

**Basically what I want is to dynamically pass a value to the folder key of the params object above.**

If I need to upload a user's profile picture then it should be stored in a "Profile" folder, if it's a product picture then in a "Products" folder etc.

"**parser**" is being passed as a middleware in the POST route above. I was thinking of adding my own middleware function before the parser middleware in which I could add a key to the request object like *req.resourceType = "product"* and then when the request reaches the parser middleware I could read the value and create a dynamic folder name. The drawback of this approach is that I would have to explicitly add the resourceType on the Frontend for the user, product and any others.

Another approach was to create separate **storage** objects and **parser** variables and pass them to the appropriate routes explicitly. For example, for creating a new product I could hardcode the folder name in the params object to "Products", for users a separate storage object with a folder name of "Users" etc.

Please suggest a better way to go about solving this problem.

Comment: The `folder` parameter in the [Cloudinary Upload API is the path in your Media Library](epasos1427@gmail.com) account where the assets will be stored (i.e., the path from `Home`). The folder is also part of public_id, which is also to be [included in the delivery URL](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_reference#overview) - and you can dynamically handle the value that you would like to put in the parameter (see [this documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#including_a_path_in_the_public_id))

Comment: @epasos_573 Thank you for the response. I was using the Multer Cloud Storage package to avoid the hassle of setting up multer manually and storing the file locally and then uploading it to cloudinary. However, after thinking about this, i feel it would be better to avoid using this package and opt for multer alone to save the file to my local disk first and then use the cloudinary API to upload it with the proper folder structure.